Submitting a signed safe erc4337 transaction on behalf of a user?
I am trying to send a safe-signed transaction to a backend, where it will be batched with another transaction and then submitted to the blockchain. What is the best approach to achieve this? I tested submitting a signed safe transaction using Postman and Pimlico on the Arbitrum blockchain, but I got an error. The safe account is owned by a single signer. The signature in the parameters below contains the full data from signatures[0].value.data.
Here is my request:
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_sendUserOperation",
    "params": [
        {
            "sender": "0xDd0D7D09E19C7F1F0fdA05f68dd7F641ca74677c",
            "nonce":"0x6d",
            "initCode":"0x",
   
            "callData":"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",
            "callGasLimit": "0x25815",
            "verificationGasLimit": "0x1b02d0",
            "preVerificationGas": "0x4e195",
            "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0xea60",
            "maxFeePerGas": "0xb71b00",
            "paymasterAndData": "0x00000000000000fb866daaa79352cc568a005d9600000066fbd74400000000000060ab7e090ba554e62e610e2c79a15a07453f3edc84a5ea94ca40f4234b67cdca4906de5ca300d54e24fffdf1dab93d31ad0a87fe829389616ead44b44d4556801c",
            "signature": signatures[0].value.data
        },

        "0x5FF137D4b0FDCD49DcA30c7CF57E578a026d2789"



    ],
    "id": 1
}

but I get the following error:
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid UserOperation signature or paymaster signature",
        "code": -32507
    }
}

What is the best way to submit a signed transaction on behalf of a user?

Would you be able to share the code you used to create signatures[0].value.data? In the meantime I would advise to use the Safe{Core} SDK for that (especially the 4337 module: https://docs.safe.global/advanced/erc-4337/guides/safe-sdk). Please let me know  Thank you in advance, Louis

`const safeCreatedTx = await safeErc4337Pack.createTransaction({
transactions: safeUserOps
})
const signedSafeOperation = await safeErc4337Pack.signSafeOperation(
safeCreatedTx
)When I call theexecuteTransactionfrom thesafeErc4337Pack` instance, everything works @Louis-SafeCoreTeam
